# PostgreSQL unexplained table bloat

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have a table in a Postgres 8.2.15 database.  The table bloated to almost 25GB but after running vacuum full and cluster the table size was dramatically smaller, well under 1GB.  A few weeks later and it's back up to 3.5GB and climbing.

This is not a table that has frequent deletes, so I'm at a loss as to what is causing the bloat.

This only happens to a single table.  I have a separate, structurally identical database, serving the same software; the table in that database has not shown any bloat.

Any ideas?

Comment: Updates also cause "bloat" - they are combination of delete and insert.

Comment: since you have two machines, I would suggest upgrading to *at least* 8.4.x

Comment: @Milen A. Radev Thanks, I'll see if I'm doing more updates here than in other places, but the bloat is pretty significant (1000% in a few weeks) - could that be just from updates?

Comment: @wildplasser They are actually on the same machine. Any reason to think that 8.4 would be better for bloat or just generally a good idea?

Comment: I don't know the exact circumstances / versions, but there have been issues with older versions, where the vacuum-process got suppressed by too much activity and the dust piled up. (and forgetting to switch on autovacuum is also a possibility, as Kenaniah suggested) Installing a fresh postgres-version in another directory / portnumber is not impossible.

Comment: Do consider updating. The vacuum implementation got a **lot** better in the last 6 years

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a least three major reasons for why you should upgrade to a more recent version, preferably to the current version.

1. As [mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/postgresql-unexplained-table-bloat/12159#comment18294_12150) the **autovacuum** mechanism has been improved in many places since version 8.2.
2. You don't see frequent `DELETE`s, so the table bloat most probably comes from `UPDATE`s as [@Milen commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/postgresql-unexplained-table-bloat/12159#comment18289_12150). A new feature has been introduced with version 8.3, that counters this problem at its root: **Heap-Only Tuples**, I quote the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/release-8-3.html#AEN88352):

   > Heap-Only Tuples (HOT) accelerate space reuse for most `UPDATE`s and
   >   `DELETE`s (Pavan Deolasee, with ideas from many others)
   >
   > `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s leave dead tuples behind, as do failed `INSERT`s.
   >   Previously only `VACUUM` could reclaim space taken by dead tuples. With
   >   HOT **dead tuple space can be automatically reclaimed** at the time of
   >   `INSERT` or `UPDATE` if no changes are made to indexed columns. This
   >   allows for more consistent performance. Also, HOT avoids adding
   >   duplicate index entries.

   Emphasis mine.
3. PostgreSQL 8.2 has reached [**end of life** in Dec. 2011](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). No more security updates. Upgrade to a more recent version as soon as possible.

To find out whether there are, in fact, a lot of `UPDATE`s launched, use the configuration parameter [**`log_statement`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) and check your **database log**. Maybe a misconfigured app or a trigger launches *a lot* more `UPDATE`s than you think?

If you `SET` the parameter in a session it only changes for this session:

```
SET log_statement = 'all';
```

So, rather change it in your `postgresql.conf`:

```
log_statement = all
```

and reload. For instance with `pg_ctl reload`. But don't forget to change it back (and reload) or your log files may grow huge. Then check the log files to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably not running autovacuum. You might want to enable that. But more importantly, you should consider upgrading to the 9.1.x branch.