# What fillfactor for caching table?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, nosql, vacuum, fill-factor

I have heavily updated / accessed table where I store serialized java objects. They are in the table for 2-3 hours (also are being updated during that period) and then removed. Size of table is around 300MB. I have spotted it is very, very often VACUUMed and wonder if changing the `fillfactor` would help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key words here are:

1. "heavily updated"
2. "in the table for 2-3 hours".

Point 1. is indication for a lower fill factor, while 2. is the opposite. It helps performance if multiple row versions are stored on the same data page. **H.O.T. updates** would achieve that. Read [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12159/3684) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806610/939860). They need some wiggle room on the data page - like dead tuples or space reserved by a `fillfactor` < 100. But they can only do their thing, if **no index involves any of the updated columns**, which should be true for your case.

Another important factor here would be the **tuple size** (in comparison to your page size (which is most commonly 8 kb). More details in this related answer:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

If the tuple size is 4 kb or more, reducing the fill factor would be futile, since there can never be more than one tuple on a data page. You might as well leave it at `100` (which is the default anyway). However, [some data types are "toasted"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) and stored out-of-line if they exceed a size limit, so tuples requiring that much in the main relation fork are rare.

Whatever you do, `VACUUM` *will* be run often. And that's generally a good thing, I wouldn't worry about that. You create lots of dead tuples. `VACUUM` identifies dead rows that are not visible to any open transaction any more. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY)

> The standard form of `VACUUM` removes dead row versions in tables and
>   indexes and **marks the space available for future reuse**.

Bold emphasis mine.
You can play with [**per-table settings** for autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) to trigger it less (or more) often for this table only:

> The default thresholds and scale factors are taken from
>   `postgresql.conf`, but it is possible to **override them on a table-by-table basis**;

Bold emphasis mine. In particular with [`autovacuum_vacuum_threshold` and `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS). Running `VACUUM` a lot might actually be a good idea, instead of a very low `fillfacter`. That depends on access patterns. If all tuples live, say, 3 hours and each is updated several times, I would still lower the `fillfactor` to something like 50. You'll have to test and find the sweet spot.

#### Alternatives

All this aside, since your data seem to be volatile to begin with: use an [`UNLOGGED` table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log
>   (see [Chapter 29](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal.html)), which makes them **considerably faster** than
>   ordinary tables. However, they are **not crash-safe**: an unlogged
>   table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown.
>   The contents of an unlogged table are also not replicated to standby servers.

Bold emphasis mine. Don't use this if your server might crash and you still need the data afterwards. But if we are talking about session data for web applications, this might be an acceptable price to pay.

Or, even more radical: Use **a key-value store like [Redis](https://redis.io/)** if you can do without the features and security provided by an RDBMS altogether.

Comment: I think UNLOGGED is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a key-value DBMS, but I throw this out there for interest's sake.

Instead of performing INSERT & DELETE statements, only do UPDATEs.

The table structure will be something like

```
ID      integer  -- sequential ID
Used    boolean  -- default FALSE
Object  -- whatever type is appropriate
```

The object-holding column will be of fixed length to avoid splits and row moves.  Size this column to accommodate your objects and to efficiently fill a page on disk.

Pre-fill your table with as many rows as you will need and a few more.

When an object is to be written find a row with Used = False and UPDATE that row.  When an object is to be destroyed, set it's Used to "False".  There is no garbage created and hence no garbage collection.

Of course there are many, many exception conditions to handle (row overflow, table overflow, race conditions on ID usage etc.) but none are insurmountable.

Comment: As far as I understand, these UPDATEs typically still write a whole new copy of the row to disk unless it's a HOT update. So you still end up needing GC/Vacuuming over time.