# Reuse subquery as in another result

Tags: postgresql, optimization, subquery

In a typical social-network-like application I have the following query that gathers **news** from a set of followed **channels**.
The main query gets the news, while the subquery gets the followed channels:

*QUERY 1: Get latest news:*

```
select n.id, n.title, n.description
from community.news n
where n.id_channel in (
       select id_channel from community.user_follows uf 
       where uf.id_user ='3d4c788e0e34657457febba2040297c7'
)
```

The app needs this table of recent news, but also needs the followed channels, so I execute the subquery again:

*QUERY 2, same as the subquery:*

```
select id_channel from community.user_follows uf 
where uf.id_user ='3d4c788e0e34657457febba2040297c7'
```

Can I optimize this? Both queries are always executed in sequence. Is it worth to use temporary tables or something like that? Or is there a way to access a subquery result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is there a way to access a subquery result?

Sure there are ways, but only in the *same* query at the next higher level.
You can extend the scope with a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), but still limited to the same query (anywhere).
To preserve a derived table across queries in the same session, materialize the result in a temporary table.
Or a regular table ([maybe `UNLOGGED`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36383/what-fillfactor-for-caching-table/36443#36443)) to extend the scope to all sessions.

What's reasonable depends on the details of your installation.

*Ideally*, you do it all in a single query, in a single query level, even. The difficulty is the return type. You have to combine columns, possibly creating some redundancy in the result. You can either reduce query time *or* reduce redundant data in the result, but not both. Combining everything into a single JSON column might be an alternative.

To get everything in a single query:

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, n.description, id_channel 
FROM   community.user_follows uf 
JOIN   community.news         n USING (id_channel)
WHERE  uf.id_user ='3d4c788e0e34657457febba2040297c7';
```