# Optimizing concurrent updates in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock, update

I'm running concurrent Postgres queries like this:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = bar + 1 WHERE baz = 1234
```

Each query affects the fixed K number of rows, and I can't find a way to enforce the order in which the rows are updated, I end up with deadlocks. Currently I fix the problem by enforcing the order by hand, but this means I have to execute many more queries than I normally would while also raising the search complexity from O(log N + K) to O(K log N).

Is there a way to improve performance without ending up vulnerable to deadlocks? I suspect that replacing the `(baz)` index with the `(baz, id)` index might work provided that Postgres updates the rows in the same order that it have scanned them, is this an approach worth pursuing?

Comment: I suggest you add the `CREATE TABLE` code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `ORDER BY` in an `SQL UPDATE` command. Postgres updates rows in arbitrary order:

- [UPDATE with ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735950/update-with-order-by/16737506#16737506)

To avoid deadlocks with absolute certainty, you could run your statements in [serializable transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE). But that's more expensive and you need to prepare to repeat commands on serialization failure.

Your best course of action is probably to lock explicitly with [**`SELECT ... ORDER BY ... FOR UPDATE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) in a subquery or a standalone `SELECT` in a transaction - in default "read committed" isolation level. [Quoting Tom Lane on pgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2382.1170171581@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> Should be all right --- the FOR UPDATE locking is always the last step
>   in the SELECT pipeline.

This should do the job:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT 1
FROM   foo 
WHERE  baz = 1234
ORDER  BY bar
FOR    UPDATE;

UPDATE foo
SET    bar = bar + 1
WHERE  baz = 1234;

COMMIT;
```

A multicolumn index on `(baz, bar)` might be perfect for performance. But since `bar` is obviously updated *a lot*, a single-column index on just `(baz)` might be even better. Depends on a couple of factors. How many rows per `baz`? Are [HOT updates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/postgresql-unexplained-table-bloat/12159#12159) possible without the multicolumn index? ...

**If** `baz` is updated concurrently, there is still an unlikely *corner case* chance for conflicts [(per documentation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html):

> It is possible for a `SELECT` command running at the `READ COMMITTED`
>   transaction isolation level and using `ORDER BY` and a locking clause to
>   return rows out of order. ...

Also, if you should have a unique constraint involving `bar`, [consider a `DEFERRABLE` constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#AEN73288) to avoid unique violations within the same command. Related answer:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)

Comment: IF I'm ordering by `id` or some other unique column instead of `bar`, there shouldn't be a corner case or a performance hit, right?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: Yes, a unique column that is never updated would be perfect for this - and a multicolumn index inlcluding this column in second position.