# Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1

Tags: postgresql, update, concurrency, queue

I have a Postgres database which contains details on clusters of servers, such as server status ('active', 'standby' etc). Active servers at any time may need to fail over to a standby, and I don't care which standby is used in particular.

I want a database query to change the status of a standby - JUST ONE - and return the server IP that is to be used. The pick can be arbitrary: since the status of the server changes with the query, it doesn't matter which standby is selected.

Is it possible to limit my query to just one update?

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE server_info SET status = 'active' 
WHERE status = 'standby' [[LIMIT 1???]] 
RETURNING server_ip;
```

Postgres doesn't like this. What could I do differently?

Comment: Just pick the server in code and add it as a where constrained. This also allows you to have additional conditions (oldest, newest, most recent alive, least loaded, same dc, different rack, least errors) checked first anyway. Most failover protocols require some form of determinism anyway.

Comment: @eckes That's an interesting idea. In my case "picking the server in code" would have meant _first_ reading a list of available servers from the db, and _then_ updating a record. Because many instances of the application could perform this action, there's a race condition and an atomic operation is needed (or was 5 years ago). The pick did not need to be deterministic.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

### Without concurrent write access

Materialize a selection in a [**CTE** (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and join to it in the `FROM` clause of the [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT server_ip          -- pk column or any (set of) unique column(s)
   FROM   server_info
   WHERE  status = 'standby'
   LIMIT  1                  -- arbitrary pick (cheapest)
   )
UPDATE server_info s
SET    status = 'active' 
FROM   cte
WHERE  s.server_ip = cte.server_ip
RETURNING s.server_ip;
```

I originally had a plain subquery here, but that can sidestep the `LIMIT` for certain query plans as [Feike](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/56047/feike) pointed out:

> The planner may choose to generate a plan that executes a nested loop over the `LIMITing` subquery, causing more `UPDATEs` than `LIMIT`, e.g.:

> ```
>  Update on buganalysis [...] rows=5
> ```

```
   ->  Nested Loop
         ->  Seq Scan on buganalysis
         ->  Subquery Scan on sub [...] loops=11
               ->  Limit [...] rows=2
                     ->  LockRows
                           ->  Sort
                                 ->  Seq Scan on buganalysis
```

> [Reproducing test case](https://github.com/feikesteenbergen/demos/blob/master/bugs/update_limit_bug.txt)

> The way to fix the above was to wrap the `LIMIT` subquery in its own CTE, as the CTE is materialized it will not return different results on different iterations of the nested loop.

***Or*** use a lowly ***correlated* subquery** for the simple case with `LIMIT` **`1`**. Simpler, faster:

```
UPDATE server_info
SET    status = 'active' 
WHERE  server_ip = (
         SELECT server_ip
         FROM   server_info
         WHERE  status = 'standby'
         LIMIT  1
         )
RETURNING server_ip;
```

### With concurrent write access

Assuming [default isolation level **`READ COMMITTED`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) for all of this. Stricter isolation levels (`REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE`) may still result in serialization errors. See:

- [SELECT … FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in REPEATABLE READ transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53288584/939860)

Under concurrent write load, add `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` to lock the row to avoid race conditions. `SKIP LOCKED` was added in Postgres **9.5**, for older versions see below. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

> With `SKIP LOCKED`, any selected rows that cannot be immediately locked
> are skipped. Skipping locked rows provides an inconsistent view of the
> data, so this is not suitable for general purpose work, but can be
> used to avoid lock contention with multiple consumers accessing a
> queue-like table.

```
UPDATE server_info
SET    status = 'active' 
WHERE  server_ip = (
         SELECT server_ip
         FROM   server_info
         WHERE  status = 'standby'
         LIMIT  1
         FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
         )
RETURNING server_ip;
```

If there is no qualifying, unlocked row left, nothing happens in this query (no row is updated) and you get an empty result. For uncritical operations that means you are done.

However, concurrent transactions may have locked rows, but then don't finish the  update (`ROLLBACK` or other reasons). ***To be sure*** run a final check:

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM server_info
   WHERE  status = 'standby'
   );
```

`SELECT` also sees locked rows. Wile that doesn't return `true`, one or more rows are still unfinished and transactions could still be rolled back. (Or new rows have been added meanwhile.) Wait a bit, then loop the two steps: (`UPDATE` till you get no row back; `SELECT` ...) until you get `true`.

Related:

- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11533623/939860)

#### Without `SKIP LOCKED` in PostgreSQL **9.4 or older**

```
UPDATE server_info
SET    status = 'active' 
WHERE  server_ip = (
         SELECT server_ip
         FROM   server_info
         WHERE  status = 'standby'
         LIMIT  1
         FOR    UPDATE
         )
RETURNING server_ip;
```

Concurrent transactions trying to lock the same row are blocked until the first one releases its lock.

If the first was rolled back, the next transaction takes the lock and proceeds normally; others in the queue keep waiting.

If the first committed, the `WHERE` condition is re-evaluated and if it's not `TRUE` any more (`status` has changed) the CTE (somewhat surprisingly) returns no row. Nothing happens. That's the desired behavior when all transactions want to update **the *same* row**.
But not when each transaction wants to update **the *next* row**. And since we just want to update an ***arbitrary* (or *random*) row**, there is no point in waiting at all.

We can unblock the situation with the help of [**advisory locks**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS):

```
UPDATE server_info
SET    status = 'active' 
WHERE  server_ip = (
         SELECT server_ip
         FROM   server_info
         WHERE  status = 'standby'
         AND    pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(id)
         LIMIT  1
         FOR    UPDATE
         )
RETURNING server_ip;
```

This way, *the next row not locked yet* will be updated. Each transaction gets a fresh row to work with. I had help from [Czech Postgres Wiki](https://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Taking_first_unlocked_row_from_table) for this trick.

`id` being any unique `bigint` column (or any type with an implicit cast like `int4` or `int2`).

<sub>If advisory locks are in use for multiple tables in your database concurrently, disambiguate with `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(tableoid::int, id)` - `id` being a unique `integer` here.

Since [`tableoid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) is a `bigint` quantity, it can theoretically overflow `integer`. If you are paranoid enough, use `(tableoid::bigint % 2147483648)::int` instead - leaving a theoretical "hash collision" for the truly paranoid ...</sub>

Also, Postgres is free to test `WHERE` conditions in any order. It *could* test  `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock()` and acquire a lock *before* `status = 'standby'`, which could result in additional advisory locks on unrelated rows, where `status = 'standby'` is not true. Related question on SO:

- [Postgres pg_try_advisory_lock blocks all records](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20115907/939860)

Typically, you can just ignore this. To *guarantee* that only qualifying rows are locked, you could nest the predicate(s) in a CTE like above or a subquery with the [`OFFSET 0` hack (prevents inlining)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14897816/939860). Example:

- [Put pg_try_advisory_xact_lock() in a nested subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162731/939860)

Or (cheaper for sequential scans) nest the conditions in a `CASE` statement like:

```
WHERE  CASE WHEN status = 'standby' THEN pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(id) END
```

**However** the `CASE` trick would also keep Postgres from using an index on `status`. If such an index is available, you don't need extra nesting to begin with: only qualifying rows will be locked in an index scan.

Since you cannot be sure that an index is used in every call, you could just:

```
WHERE  status = 'standby'
AND    CASE WHEN status = 'standby' THEN pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(id) END
```

The `CASE` is logically redundant, but it servers the discussed purpose.

If the command is part of a long transaction, consider session-level locks that can be (and have to be) released manually. So you can unlock as soon as you are done with the locked row: [`pg_try_advisory_lock()` and `pg_advisory_unlock()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)

> Once acquired at session level, an advisory lock is held until
> explicitly released or the session ends.

Related:

- [Optimizing concurrent updates in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/optimizing-concurrent-updates-in-postgres/68398#68398)

Comment: If I add an `ORDER BY` inside the CTE, will the data returned be in that order? (i.e. does `RETURNING` adhere to the order in the CTE)

Comment: Since postgres 13, CTEs are not necessarily materialised. Does that mean the problem of certain query plans ignoring the limit has started happening even with a CTE?