# PostgreSQL How to optimize a query with ORDER BY and LIMIT 1?

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, order-by, limits

I have the following PostgreSQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE BOX (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_item;

CREATE TABLE Item (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('seq_item'),
    SENDER INTEGER REFERENCES User(id),
    RECEIVER INTEGER REFERENCES User(id),
    INFO TEXT,
    BOX_ID INTEGER REFERENCES Box(id) NOT NULL,
    ARRIVAL TIMESTAMP
);
```

Its main use case is a typical producer/consumer scenario. Different users may insert an item in the database in a particular box for a particular user and each user can retrieve the topmost(this means the oldest) item in a box that is addressed to her/him. It more or less mimics the functionality of a queue on a database level.

More precisely, the most common operations are the following:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM(SENDER, RECEIVER, INFO, BOX_ID, ARRIVAL) 
VALUES (nsid, nrid, ncontent, nqid, ntime);
```

And retrieve commands based on a combination of either `RECEIVER+SENDER` or `RECEIVER+BOX_ID`:

```
SELECT * INTO it FROM Item i WHERE (i.RECEIVER=? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
(i.BOX_ID=?) ORDER BY ARRIVAL LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM Item i WHERE i.id=it.id;
```

and

```
SELECT * INTO it FROM Item i WHERE (i.RECEIVER=? OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) AND 
(i.SENDER=?) ORDER BY ARRIVAL LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM Item i WHERE i.id=it.id;
```

The last two snippets are packed within a stored procedure.

I was wondering how to achieve best performance given this use case and knowing that the users will insert and retrieve somewhere between `50,000` and `500,000` items (however, the database is never expected to contain more than `100,000` items at a given point)?

**EDIT**

This is the `EXPLAIN` I get with for the `SELECT` statements no indexes:

```
Limit (cost=23.07..23.07 rows=1 width=35)
   -> Sort (cost=23.07..25.07 rows=799 width=35)
      Sort Key: ARRIVAL
      -> Seq Scan on Item i (cost=0.00..19.07 rows=799 width=35)
         Filter: (((RECEIVER = 1) OR (RECEIVER IS NULL)) AND (SENDER = 1))
```

The best `EXPLAIN` I get based on my understanding is when I put an index on the time(`CREATE INDEX ind ON Item(ARRIVAL);`):

```
Limit (cost=0.42..2.88 rows=1 width=35)
   -> Index Scan using ti on Item i (cost=0.42..5899.42 rows=2397 width=35)
      Filter: (((receiver = 2) OR (RECEIVER IS NULL)) AND (SENDER = 2))
```

In all of the cases without index on `ARRIVAL` I have to sort the table which seems to my inefficient. If I try to combine an index on `ARRIVAL` and `RECEIVER/SENDER` I get the same explanation, but slightly slower.

Is it correct to assume that a single index on `ARRIVAL` is the most efficient option?

Comment: For just 800 rows, Postgres (or any other DBMS) will usually never use an index. Unrelated, but: using `select ... into ..` to create a table is discouraged. You should use the standard compliant `create table as` instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I edited the question and included further details.

Comment: `user` is a reserved word and illegal as identifier without double quotes. The syntax of your `DELETE` statements is wrong. Your question would be more useful if you provided a working test case. And, as *always*, your version of Postgres. Also consider using a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column. And most importantly, your whole idea is not safe for concurrent use. Multiple transactions can fetch the same row before it is deleted. Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684

Answer (score 3):

A btree index on `(sender,arrival)` could help.  That would allow it to jump directly to the first-arrived message for a given sender.

One on `(arrival,sender)` is less likely to help.  That allows you to jump to the first-sent message globally, but then you still have to walk along those messages until you hit one from the specified sender.  If that particular sender is new, or only sends messages to people who keep up on their inbox, then you might have to walk through most of the index  before you find a qualifying message.  It might help in that you only have to walk the index, not the index and table combined, but that would still be a much smaller win than the proper index of `(sender,arrival)`.

Similarly, you would want another index on `(box_id, arrival)`, not on `(arrival, box_id)`.

Also, performance testing on a table with 800 rows is useless if the real table will have 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

The planner chooses use of a index depending on the distribution of data in your tables. If you have lots of receivers  with only a few arrivals per receiver it will prefer a  index like (receiver,arrival), if all arrivals are shared by only a handful of users the (arrival,receiver) index will be much more efficient. Make sure to run ANALYZE on the table after loading sample data. Don't hesitate to create both indexes and consult the postgres usage statistics after a few days of operation (pg_stat_all_indexes) to determine which is worth to keep.

Please reconsider the use of NULL values for sender, receiver or box in your queries. What does a item-record mean, if there is no receiver or no box? In general it is not a good idea to allow this on foreign key constrains.

Comment: About the 'in general' part - I don't agree.  For example, there might be a car without an owner, right?  What you say about NULLs is point on this specific case, though.

Comment: Yes, there may be exceptions, but in this case it is better to create a user names  "unknown" with a known ID than to  handle NULL case in every query. If the foreign key is primary  on the other side as it is the situation here you can not insert anyway. And honestly i've never seen a car without owner.

Comment: That's not true - a NULL can always be inserted in a nullable FK column.  Aren't there unsold cars, BTW?

Comment: I said  'in this case' the fk references PK of table 'User' which must not be NULL and so you can not insert a row  into the item-table wit NULL for the fields sender or receiver. My basic intention here was pointing to the  " ... OR i.RECEIVER is NULL) ..." in Ivaylos query examples which are possiblu superfluous. 
ps: if a unsold car has now owner, i should go and claim one for free :-)

Comment: Obviously, I was only reflecting on the 'in general' part.  As clearly written above.

Comment: @ClausKoch We all know that the PK of a table is `NOT NULL` by default and no way around that. But what an FK column references (whether it references a PK or a nullable UNIQUE column or a not nullable UNIQUE column) is irrelevant. What matters is whether the FK column is nullable or not. If it is nullable, you can very well insert a `NULL` in it. Even if it references a `NOT NULL` pk column.

Comment: @ypercube: You say you can insert a NULL into a FK column which references a PK? Very interesting.  Which row in the primary table will it reference?

Comment: @ClausKoch This is the standard SQL behaviour. All DBMS I know (Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL) implement FKs this way. Obviously a NULL value will not reference any row in the primary table.