# How to update an element in json array with where clause?

Tags: postgresql, update, json

I came across this question on [how to update nth element of array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193390/update-nth-element-of-array-using-a-where-clause), but it has nested json values in it instead of a plain array of strings.

Here are some sample json values from jsonb column of the table.

```
{"pattern": {"values": ["foo", "edfgh"]}}
{"pattern": {"values": ["abc", "abdhi", "foo"]}}
{"pattern": {"values": ["these", "abcd", "para", "avil"]}}
```

We can select the nth element using

```
select data #> '{pattern, values, 0}' from table;
```

How can we loop through array and update `foo` to `bar` if it is present in that array?

Comment: Json values are not valid please correct that

Comment: @SahapAsci Corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Copy of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193390/update-nth-element-of-array-using-a-where-clause

Comment: @A.J.Alger The question is not the same. The value `foo` can be anywhere in array.

Comment: how about if there is more than one `"foo"` in the array ?

Comment: It should replace both of them in place without changing order. @SahapAsci

Answer (score 3):

You can use a query like the one below;

```
UPDATE table SET
  data = jsonb_set(data,'{pattern, values}', ((data->'pattern'->'values') - 'foo') ||  '["bar"]' )
WHERE
  (data #> '{pattern, values}') ? 'foo';
```

**Details;**

First you have to find records which have "foo" value in "values" array;

```
(data #> '{pattern, values}') ? 'foo'
```

After that remove the value "foo" from the array;

```
((data->'pattern'->'values') - 'foo')
```

Create a new array by concatenating your new value(s).

```
((data->'pattern'->'values') - 'foo') ||  '["bar"]'
```

Replace new array with the old one.

```
jsonb_set(data,'{pattern, values}', new_array)
```

Comment: This replaces the element but doesn't preserve the order. Is there a way to update it and preserve order also?