# Deadlock in AFTER INSERT trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, deadlock, concurrency

I have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger for table A that updates multiple rows in table B (incrementing a column in table B). Normally, the web server would insert multiple rows into table A using a single insert statement with the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, which would cause the trigger to fire for each row inserted. As there are multiple web servers at once, there will always be multiple concurrent insert statements/transactions.

Initially, this led to Postgres reporting deadlocks when the trigger was updating the rows in table B. To address this, I changed the trigger function to update the rows in table B in the order of their PK:

```
UPDATE table_b
SET counter = counter + 1
WHERE ctid = ANY(ARRAY(
  SELECT ctid FROM table_b
  WHERE name = 'some name' AND store = 'store id'
  ORDER BY id
  FOR UPDATE
))
```

The deadlocks were still happening after this change. I thought the above statement didn't work, so I changed it to use a PL/pgSQL `FOR` loop:

```
FOR row_b IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table_b
    WHERE name = 'some name' AND store = 'store id'
    ORDER BY id
)
LOOP
    UPDATE table_b
    SET counter = counter + 1
    WHERE id = row_b.id;
END LOOP;
```

But this also didn't work and deadlocks were still happening. The source of the deadlock was reported to be at the update statement of table B (when incrementing the `counter` of the row). This was the exact error reported by Postgres:

> Process 316 waits for ShareLock on transaction 850467907; blocked by process 426.
> Process 426 waits for ShareLock on transaction 850467903; blocked by process 316.

I'm confused about how a deadlock could still happen in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with trying to acquire locks in a consistent sort order. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS)

> The best defense against deadlocks is generally to avoid them by being
> certain that all applications using a database acquire locks on
> multiple objects in a consistent order.

However, your implementation does not actually achieve that. You write:

> - `AFTER INSERT` trigger for table A that updates multiple rows in table B ...
> - ... insert multiple rows into table A using a single insert statement with the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level

By sorting target rows in table B per inserted row in table A, you only achieve a partial sort. Nothing keeps earlier rows from table A in one transaction to update later rows in table B and vice versa. You would have to enforce a consistent sort order for the whole set of rows that are write-locked in table B over the course of the same transaction. And you would have to take all locks on table A first, also in consistent sort order.

Assuming a trigger `FOR EACH ROW`, that's not how it works. The manual:

> PostgreSQL offers both per-row triggers and per-statement triggers.
> With a per-row trigger, the trigger function is invoked once for each
> row that is affected by the statement that fired the trigger. In
> contrast, a per-statement trigger is invoked only once when an
> appropriate statement is executed, regardless of the number of rows
> affected by that statement.

There are various ways to get around this.

- Insert only a single row in table A in the same transaction. (More expensive. May be tedious.)
- Use the [`SERIALIZABLE` isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE). (More expensive. And you need to be prepared to repeat transactions on serialization failure.)
- Use a statement-level trigger. (May be tricky or impossible.)
- Manual locking on involved rows in table A and table B before executing the `INSERT` (and the triggered `UPDATE`) statements.

But first I would investigate if you actually need that trigger to increment multiple rows in table B. That's expensive even under ideal circumstances. Maybe there is a smarter approach, starting with a better DB schema?

Related:

- [Why am I getting a deadlock for a single UPDATE query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257217/why-am-i-getting-a-deadlock-for-a-single-update-query/257229#257229)
- [How to prevent deadlocks in many-to-many insert/update trigger function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223598/how-to-prevent-deadlocks-in-many-to-many-insert-update-trigger-function/223607#223607)