# select rows on distinct column value without vendor-specific sql syntax

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, db2, distinct

I'm trying to select distinct rows without any vendor specific syntax. My table layout is as follows:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
|                  id                  | version |        jobAsJson         |        jobSignature        |   state    |   createdAt   |   updatedAt   | scheduledAt | serverTag |                mutex                 | awaitingOn | isBatch |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
| 6b56ef47-46e2-4905-9b4e-d8923306f98d |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | PROCESSING | 1594385831872 | 1594385831872 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-a                           | null       |       0 |
| c0514d03-5bd1-494f-9978-dfbc24f06d67 |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385832874 | 1594385832874 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-a                           | null       |       0 |
| 6b33ef73-8aa7-4d83-a171-b30da6a95c5f |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385833874 | 1594385833874 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-a                           | null       |       0 |
| d4d75118-57cc-476c-a86d-a6b73fc30d37 |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385834874 | 1594385834874 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-a                           | null       |       0 |
| 2cfbf072-5233-496d-9236-28e66cddf054 |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385835874 | 1594385835874 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-b                           | null       |       0 |
| d8f2d419-f394-4d4b-b375-4f1611b28170 |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385836875 | 1594385836875 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-b                           | null       |       0 |
| 3cdf7878-0716-4928-a059-2a74b4172c74 |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385837875 | 1594385837875 | null        | DEFAULT   | resource-c                           | null       |       0 |
| d0bfffac-9d5b-4c7e-a82b-ca0f93d1a1da |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385838875 | 1594385838875 | null        | DEFAULT   | 79333f04-ab41-41dc-b004-8b2d74055d38 | null       |       0 |
| c1d568f3-f1e1-4d4d-9ca5-21129bf6d066 |       0 | {some json value I want} | System.out.println(String) | ENQUEUED   | 1594385839875 | 1594385839875 | null        | DEFAULT   | 1b8b941c-6bdc-45cf-93b5-1856f9de404a | null       |       0 |
+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------+----------------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to select all rows where state = 'ENQUEUED', servertag is in ('DEFAULT'), the rows should be ordered by createdAt **AND** the rows should be unique on the field mutex.

The goal is to only have 1 row with state = 'PROCESSING' for each mutex. The selected rows with STATE='ENQUEUED' will be updated to 'PROCESSING'. In the example here, the expected results are:

- 2cfbf072-5233-496d-9236-28e66cddf054 -> first job with mutex = resource-b
- 3cdf7878-0716-4928-a059-2a74b4172c74 -> first job with mutex = resource-c
- d0bfffac-9d5b-4c7e-a82b-ca0f93d1a1da -> no mutex thus unique value to make query easier
- c1d568f3-f1e1-4d4d-9ca5-21129bf6d066 -> no mutex thus unique value to make query easier

=> no job with mutex resource-a is returned as it is already being used by the first job.

The query I have now works for SQLite but not for other databases (mySQL, oracle, DB2) and is as follows:

```
select 
    j.jobAsJson 
from 
    (select id 
     from jobrunr_jobs 
     where state = 'ENQUEUED' 
     AND servertag in ('DEFAULT') 
     and mutex NOT IN (select mutex from jobrunr_jobs where state = 'PROCESSING') 
     GROUP BY mutex order by createdat) r 
INNER JOIN 
    jobrunr_jobs j ON r.id = j.id
```

I would like to have a query that is database vendor agnostic.

Postgres and SQL Server complain about the fact that a `GROUP BY` is used and `id` is not part of it.

Comment: Can we also assume a `mutex` table in the database? Holding one row per distinct (relevant) mutex. That would allow cheaper queries - and also cheaper locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Errors?

First off, I suspect a subtle error in your query:

```
...
AND servertag IN ('DEFAULT') 
AND mutex NOT IN (select mutex from jobrunr_jobs where state = 'PROCESSING') 
...
```

You limit results to mutex with servertag 'DEFAULT', but the restriction is not repeated in the `NOT IN` subquery. So you exclude mutex that have a row with state 'PROCESSING' and *any* servertag. *May* be intentional, but it smells like an error. Even if nothing breaks (because of mutually exclusive sets of mutex values), it is probably still bad for performance.

Also, `mutex NOT IN (<subselect>)` is a notoriously treacherous construct. If `mutex` can be NULL, the query will break unexpectedly. [In Postgres, this construct is generally discouraged.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN) I assume the same is true for most RDBMS.

#### Query

Basically, you want the latest row per mutex with `state = 'ENQUEUED'` where no row with `state = 'PROCESSING'` exists. I *assume* you want to restrict both conditions to rows with `servertag = 'DEFAULT'`:

```
SELECT jobAsJson          -- careful with mixed-case spelling!
FROM   jobrunr_jobs AS j
WHERE  state = 'ENQUEUED'
AND    servertag = 'DEFAULT'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   jobrunr_jobs AS j2
   WHERE  j2.mutex = j.mutex
   AND    j2.servertag = 'DEFAULT'  -- assuming you want this?
   AND   (j2.state = 'PROCESSING'
       OR j2.state = 'ENQUEUED' AND j2.createdat > j.createdat)
   );
```

`EXISTS` is very basic standard SQL, and work in every halfway decent RDBMS - unlike CTEs and window functions, which are later additions and not supported everywhere.

Also removes the need for the dubious `NOT IN`.

And it should be *fast*, especially with index support.

Aside 1: to be "DB-agnostic" (which is never fully possible) don't use mixed-case identifiers, which are treated differently across various RDBMS.

Aside 2: Assuming you then want to mark identified rows as `'PROCESSING'`. Then you'll want to return more than just `jobAsJson`. Or `UPDATE` identified rows right away. See:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

Comment: Hi @erwin-brandstetter - thanks, I would never been able to create that query. Two more questions:
- I assume I also can use `servertag in ('DEFAULT')` and `j2.servertag in ('DEFAULT')` as sometimes there will be 'DEFAULT', 'LINUX' for example

- if I would add an extra column called priority which is an integer from 0 to 5, would it be possible to first return the rows where priority is smaller (e.g. 0 is most important, then 1, ...). If priority of the each row is equal, it returns the rows where createdAt is the smallest

Comment: @rdehuyss: Yes, `servertag in ('DEFAULT')` is equivalent to `servertag = 'DEFAULT'`, just more noisy. About `priority`: certainly possible. Please ask the new question in a new question. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context and drop a comment here to link back (and get my attention). But be sure to be crystal clear about your requirements. Details may matter.

Answer (score 2):

The error is normal as your query groups by the mutex which produce more then 1 rows/ID per "group". SQL cannot guess on the ID that you want to see.

To fix this, you need to write your query in a way that SQL knows which line to return. Using the "row_number" function is usually the easiest way to achieve it.

Here's an example :

```
create table #Demo (id uniqueidentifier, State varchar(20), createdAt BIGINT, mutex varchar(20));
insert into #Demo values ('6b56ef47-46e2-4905-9b4e-d8923306f98d','PROCESSING',1594385831872,'resource-a'),
('c0514d03-5bd1-494f-9978-dfbc24f06d67','ENQUEUED',1594385832874,'resource-a'),
('6b33ef73-8aa7-4d83-a171-b30da6a95c5f','ENQUEUED',1594385833874 ,'resource-a'),
('d4d75118-57cc-476c-a86d-a6b73fc30d37','ENQUEUED',1594385834874 ,'resource-a'),
('2cfbf072-5233-496d-9236-28e66cddf054','ENQUEUED',1594385835874 ,'resource-b'),
('d8f2d419-f394-4d4b-b375-4f1611b28170','ENQUEUED',1594385836875  ,'resource-b'),
('3cdf7878-0716-4928-a059-2a74b4172c74','ENQUEUED',1594385837875  ,'resource-c');
go

with A as (
select ID, mutex, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by mutex order by createdAt) "RN" from #Demo
where State='ENQUEUED'
and mutex not in (select mutex from #Demo where State='PROCESSING') --To exclude mutex which are already processing
)
select ID, mutex 
from A where RN=1

drop table #Demo
```