# Locking row for INSERT, still getting duplicate key exception

Tags: postgresql, locking, upsert

I am trying to run the following query:

```
WITH upd AS (
  UPDATE fila_all SET id = id WHERE
  id = (select id from fila_all fa where fa.id not in (select msg_id from fila_consumers where group_name = 'group0') and fa.queue_name = 'myqueue' order by id asc limit 1 for update of fa skip locked)
  returning id
)
INSERT INTO fila_consumers select fa2.id, 'new-worker0', 'group0', 'Running'
FROM fila_all fa2 JOIN upd on upd.id = fa2.id
RETURNING msg_id
```

`id` is a primary key on fila_all, and `(msg_id, group_name)` is a primary key on `fila_consumers`.

`fila_consumers` only has four columns, id bigint, worker_name varchar, group varchar, status enum.

I would expect this query to never fail due to a conflict on `fila_consumers_pk`, because the rows are locked, and skipped, on the update, so two transactions cannot get the same `fila_all.id` for insertion in `fila_consumers`. But I get the following error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "fila_consumers_pkey"
    Detail: Key (msg_id, group_name)=[...]
```

I don't want to use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, I'd like to understand why this is happening.

All insertions on fila_consumers are based on this statement, multiple instances of this statement run concurrently, but no other statements are executed that insert on this table.

What am I missing here? Is there a way around this?

Comment: `fila_consumers only has tree columns`. But you are inserting 4 expressions: `INSERT INTO fila_consumers select fa2.id, 'new-worker0', 'group0', 'Running'`. And the quoted error msg. disagrees, too: `Key (msg_id, group_name)`. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about status, yes 4 columns

Comment: Could someone downvoting please explain why? Yes I had some typos, but not sure why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `INSERT` targets the right columns, which we can't tell without table definition and target definition list.

The statement boils down to this:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT fa.id, {GROUP}, {worker}, 'Running'
   FROM   fila_all fa
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM fila_consumers fc
      WHERE  fc.msg_id = fa.id
      AND    fc.group_name = {GROUP}
      )
   AND    fa.queue_name = {queue}
   ORDER  BY fa.id
   LIMIT  1
   FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
   )
                         -- target definition list!
INSERT INTO fila_consumers (msg_id, group_name, col3, col4)
TABLE  cte
RETURNING msg_id;
```

You are locking a row in table `fila_all` (twice over in the original). So multiple instances of the same query cannot insert duplicate rows in table `fila_consumers`, coming from the same source. Good.

**But** there is nothing to prevent **other concurrent transactions** from inserting / updating rows in `fila_consumers` in the time window between the `SELECT` and the `INSERT`.

The expensive empty `UPDATE` in your original makes this window much bigger than necessary. My version with only `SELECT` should minimize the problem. And `NOT EXISTS` is typically faster than `NOT IN`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

But the problem is still there.

Any particular reason you are trying to avoid `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`?
That UPSERT functionality was added to fix your kind of problems.

Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "But there is nothing to prevent other concurrent transactions from inserting [...]" ? all other transactions would be using the same select/insert, or just a normal insert on fila_all. the purpose of `for update` and `skip locked` was for the statement to continue to the next available row in fila_all to be inserted into fila_consumers, and so two transactions would not conflict, as they would try to insert different rows, so I wouldn't need `ON CONCLICT DO NOTHING`

Comment: Could you please clarify your question first? You saw my leading assumpions, right? Also put information on concurrent transactions there.

Comment: I changed the question now. though I don't know what you mean by `group <> group_name` typo, `{group}` was a placeholder for a query param.

Comment: @simao: `(msg_id, group) is a primary key on fila_consumers.` <> `(msg_id, group_name)`

Comment: ah yes, typo, sorry. Thank you for you help.