# PostgreSQL relative update breaks unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, index, update, unique-constraint, upsert

I have unique index on column for UPSERT. When I am trying to update column using `v = v + 1` expression my unique index breaks.

##### SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(v bigint, data jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO test(v) SELECT vv FROM generate_series(0, 10000) as vv;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_ind ON test(v);
```

```sql
UPDATE test SET v = v + 1;
```

##### What I've tried:

1. Using deferred constraint, but it doesn't work with UPSERT.
2. Using `CLUSTER` to order rows on disk, so update will have specific order and won't break index. Problem is I have to call `CLUSTER` before each query which is very expensive.
3. Implementing UPSERT by hand seems complicated and non performant. (postgres wiki agrees with me on it https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT#PostgreSQL_.28today.29)
4. Using multicolumn unique index `(v, flag)`. For this I need to add flag column and replace index

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN flag bool DEFAULT false;
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_ind ON test(v, flag);
   ```

   Then UPDATE and UPSERT looks like

   ```sql
   -- UPDATE
   UPDATE test SET v = v + 1, flag = true;
   UPDATE test SET flag = false;
   --UPSERT
   INSERT INTO test(v) VALUES (123) ON CONFLICT (v, flag) DO UPDATE SET v = EXCLUDED.v;
   ```

   But it has x2 cost compared to simple update. For now it's most suitable solution.

What is alternatives for UPDATE case or for UPSERT case so I can:

1. Efficiently UPSERT rows. (this operation is dominant)
2. Update many records with expressions like `v = v + 1`.

Scale is around 1k-10k rows per update. And around 1m-10m records in the table.

Comment: What is the purpose of incrementing `v` this way? What is it tracking?

Comment: Yes, the best solution is probably to avoid that update. Perhaps you can calculate `v` on select.

Comment: I've tried to simplify example. Actually I use `row` and `col`  for storing data for excel like table cells.

Comment: @Olleggerr: We can only answer the question as given. If your "real" question is substantially different, I suggest you start a new question, this time presenting what you really want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second Laurenz' comment: typically it's best to avoid such an update on a `UNIQUE` column to begin with.

If that's not possible, one workaround would be to order rows in a subquery and self-join:

```
UPDATE test t
SET    v = t.v + 1
FROM  (SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY v DESC) t_ordered  -- additional  WHERE clauses?
WHERE  t_ordered.v = t.v;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26a7b4fad7855fe70107354127660f2e)*

This usually works. But no rows are locked in the subquery, so the command is not bullet-proof against concurrent writes. If you want that, you'll have to write-lock the whole table, or use [`SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE). Either is expensive for concurrent access.

Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

Also, you mentioned:

> 1k-10k rows per update. And around 1m-10 rows in the table.

So the `UPDATE` can still conflict with rows that are not updated.

To update the **whole table**, consider dropping the `UNIQUE` constraint before the update and recreate it after, in the same transaction. That takes an exclusive write-lock, of course. But that seems ok while updating the whole table. Recreating the index is cheaper than incrementally updating all rows anyway, and you get a pristine (de-bloated, reindexed) unique index as side effect.
Conflicts with FK constraints pointing to the `UNIQUE` column, though ...

Comment: I've tried to simplify example. Actually I use row and col for storing data for excel like table cells. So real structure is something like `cells(row int, col int, sheet_id uuid, data text)`. And UNIQUE index on `(col, row, sheet_id)`. Also I lazily write cells, so I am using UPSERT for this