# Is clustering a table beneficial, given this update pattern?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, update, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table essentially equivalent to this example:

```
create table my_table(i integer, x text, y integer, z integer);

create index idx_i_x on my_table(i, x);
create index idx_i_y on my_table(i, y);
create index idx_i_z on my_table(i, z);
create index idx_i_x on my_table(i, x, y, z);
```

All queries have column `i` in the where clause.

It seems that this table is a good candidate to benefit from 
table clustering (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-cluster.html)

Stats on my_table: for each value of `i`, there will be from 5 to 10 million rows.

Updates on the table follow the pattern:

```
update my_table set i = 4 where i = 0;

delete from my_table where i = 6;
```

All updates or deletes are "bulk", i.e. they 
involve all rows for a given value of i.

Given what is written in the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-cluster.html) :

> Clustering is a one-time operation: when the table is subsequently
>   updated, the changes are not clustered.

it seems as if it doesn't matter that rows are not reclustered for updates of i, since when I execute this update (for example) :

```
update my_table set i = 4 where i = 0;
```

all rows that had `i = 0` are still clustered together.

Comment: what does x,y,z stand for?

Comment: x,y,z are arbitrary columns, for the purpose of this example we could assume they are random and have non predictable (or random) access patterns

Comment: Beneficial for what exactly? Which other queries (other than the UPDATE you mentioned) are sensitive to performance? Is that your *actual* table definition? Can columns be NULL like your table definition suggests? Which index is used for clustering the table? Do you need all those indexes? What is your Postgres version? Do you have concurrent (write-) access? How many distinct values for `i`? Are you at liberty to change the DB layout?

Answer (score 1):

`CLUSTER` helps read performance where actual table rows have to be read (from the main relation). Index-only scans don't care about the physical order of rows in the underlying table. If your table layout is that simple, you might cover almost all `SELECT` queries with index-only scans (Might require aggressive autovacuum settings for the table to support that.)

`UPDATE` performance may even suffer from `CLUSTER`. First of all, `CLUSTER` rewrites the table without dead tuples, thereby removing "wiggle-room" for H.O.T. updates. A lower `FILLFACTOR` might help, but not in your case. While updating indexed columns, H.O.T. updates are not possible anyway.

- [PostgreSQL Initial Database Size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/postgresql-initial-database-size/21507#21507)
- [PostgreSQL unexplained table bloat](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/postgresql-unexplained-table-bloat/12159#12159)

While you update millions of rows in one command (or transaction), clustered together, new row versions will hardly ever find room on the same data page, which makes it a bit more expensive to begin with.

And since you have multiple indexes including the updated columns, your updates are particularly expensive, since all of these indexes need to be updated as well.

Dead rows have to be reclaimed eventually. So new rows are not always written "en bloc", which inevitably leads to (slow in your case) fragmentation over time.

#### More efficient approach?

> for each value of `i`, there will be from 5 to 10 million rows.
> ...
> All updates or deletes are "bulk", i.e. they involve all rows for a given value of `i`.

Seems like you should not be updating millions of rows to begin with. Instead, create a second table (1:n) with a single row for every distinct `i` in `my_table`:

```
CREATE TABLE current_i (
   org_i     integer PRIMARY KEY
 , current_i integer NOT NULL  -- UNIQUE?
);
```

Should be a very small table, given your specifications. Now you only update a ***single*** row in `current_i` instead of millions in `my_table`, saving a lot of bloat and vacuuming in `my_table` and its indexes - in addition to the much faster updates - which should make everything else faster, too.

To enforce referential integrity, you may want to add a [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) to `my_table.i`:

```
REFERENCES current_i(i)
```

In queries, just join to `current_i`. You might provide a `VIEW` as drop-in replacement for the current table in `SELECT` queries:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT i.current_i AS i, m.x, m.y, m.z
FROM   my_table  m
JOIN   current_i i ON i.org_i = m.i;
```

Should be *much* faster overall. All of this may come down to a simple case of ***normalization***.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems as if it doesn't matter that rows are not reclustered for updates of i, since when I execute this update (for example) :

When a row is updated, it's essentially deleted and rewritten. Where that row gets rewritten is a function of the space available in the table. If for instance, there are dead rows those rows may once against be segmented to fit within the dead rows inside the table.

So you have a chance it'll work as you want, but it may not too.